# Import Error: No module named testrunner

Tags: python, plone, importerror, buildout

I followed [this](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/upgrade-guide/version/upgrading-plone-3-x-to-4.0/updating-add-on-products-for-plone-4.0/no-longer-bin-instance-test-use-zc.recipe.testrunner) to add `zc.recipe.testrunner` to my buildout. I can run buildout successfully but when I run `bin/test`, I get:

```
ImportError: No module named testrunner
```

I have `zope.testrunner-4.0.4-py2.4.egg` in

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages
```

I also pinned

```
zope.testrunner = 4.0.4
zc.recipe.testruner = 1.4.0
zc.recipe.egg = 1.3.2
```

When I ran buildout, I used `-vvv` and I got:

```
...
Installing 'zc.recipe.testrunner'.
We have the distribution that satisfies 'zc.recipe.testrunner==1.4.0'.
Egg from site-packages: z3c.recipe.scripts 1.0.1
Egg from site-packages: zope.testrunner 4.0.4
Egg from site-packages: zope.interface 3.8.0
Egg from site-packages: zope.exceptions 3.7.1
...
We have the distribution that satisfies 'zope.testrunner==4.0.4'.
Egg from site-packages: zope.testrunner 4.0.4
Adding required 'zope.interface'
 required by zope.testrunner 4.0.4.
We have a develop egg: zope.interface 0.0
Adding required 'zope.exceptions'
 required by zope.testrunner 4.0.4.
We have a develop egg: zope.exceptions 0.0
...
```

Why is it I get an ImportError? Is zope.testrunner not installed correctly?

**Edit:**

**This is the relevant part in my buildout:**

```
[buildout]
...
parts =
    ...
    test

[test]
recipe = zc.recipe.testrunner
defaults = ['--auto-color', '--auto-progress']
eggs = 
    my.product
```

**This is the content in `bin/test`:**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.4 -S

import sys
sys.path[0:0] = [
    '/home/jil/mySandbox/myTrunk/parts/test/site-packages',
    ]


import os
path = sys.path[0]
if os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH'):
    path = os.pathsep.join([path, os.environ['PYTHONPATH']])
os.environ['BUILDOUT_ORIGINAL_PYTHONPATH'] = os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH', '')
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = path
import site # imports custom buildout-generated site.py
import os
sys.argv[0] = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
os.chdir('/home/jil/mySandbox/myTrunk/parts/test/working-directory')

import zope.testrunner

if __name__ == '__main__':
    zope.testrunner.run((['--auto-color', '--auto-progress']) + [
        '--test-path', '/home/jil/mySandbox/myTrunk/src/my.product',
        ])
```

**This is the error after running `bin/test`:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jil/mySandbox/myTrunk/bin/test", line 20, in ?
  import zope.testrunner
ImportError: No module named testrunner
```

Comment: Show us the configuration for the test section of your buildout, and the contents of the bin/test script that buildout generated.

Comment: and possibly the complete traceback of the error

Comment: Somehow generated bin/test script is invalid. It might be that testrunner is compatible only with Python 2.6 + Plone 4?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I'm using Plone3/Python2.4. It says [here](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/upgrade-guide/version/upgrading-plone-3-x-to-4.0/updating-add-on-products-for-plone-4.0/no-longer-bin-instance-test-use-zc.recipe.testrunner) that zc.recipe.testrunner is compatible with Plone 4, Plone 3 and Plone 2.5.x. In addition, zc.recipe.testrunner depends on zope.testrunner (which depends on zope.interface and zope.exceptions).[zope.testrunner](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.testrunner) never mentions removing Python2.4 support.

Comment: In any case there are no any eggs in your bin/test script's sys.path so it cannot potentially work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. At least in my case, the cause was mixing dependencies already installed in 'site-packages' and dependencies installed by buildout in 'eggs': zope.deprecation and zope.interface were already in my 'site-packages' directory and thus were not re-installed by buildout. The path manipulation on the 'bin/test' executable seemed to import the 'zope' package from 'site-packages', without the 'testrunner' subpackage.

Try removing all zope.* packages from 'site-packages' and re-run buildout, or use 'include-site-packages = false' in the '[buildout]' section of your buildout.cfg. The first solution worked for me.

Comment: This answer helped, thank you. Didn't need the `include-site-packages`, just created a new virtualenv and installed buildout only in it, that worked.